# Одноврéменно и одновремéнно?

Tags: орфоэпия

Современные словари разрешают говорить и так и так. Хотя еще совсем недавно в них вроде было только одно нормативное ударение в этом слове: одноврéменно.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Из статьи [Почему существует вариативность в ударении? | thequestion.ru](https://thequestion.ru/questions/83579/pochemu-sushestvuet-variativnost-v-udarenii)

Надо признать, что носители языка, далекие от лингвистики, обычно считают наличие вариантов едва ли не «болезнью» языка, а ответ филолога «правильно и так и так» воспринимается либо как незнание правильного ответа, либо как нежелание отвечать на вопрос. Всё это, конечно же, не так. Если мы открываем словарь и видим там: «одноврЕменно» и «одновремЕнно», это вовсе не означает, что с языком что-то не так или что безвольный автор словаря не решился выбрать один вариант. **Это означает, что сегодня между этими вариантами идет конкуренция, обеспечивающая плавный переход от одной нормы к другой**.

2) Так какая норма является старшей, какая новой и прогрессивной? Или они просто колеблются, пытаясь вытеснить друг друга?

[Как правильно ставить ударение в слове «одновременно» | kakprosto.ru](http://www.kakprosto.ru/kak-915012-kak-pravilno-stavit-udarenie-v-slove-odnovremenno)

Нормы русского языка со временем меняются, и правила постановки ударения в слове «одновременно» за последние столетия изменились тоже. **Так, в знаменитом словаре Владимира Даля, составленном в середине XIX века, правильное ударение в слове «одноврЕменно» указывалось на третьем слоге. В «Словаре неправильностей русской речи» Долопчева, вышедшего в 1909 году, в качестве нормативного также указывался именно этот вариант.**

Некоторые из авторов более современных словарей и справочников русского языка до сих пор отдают преимущество ударению «одноврЕменно»,  считая, однако, вариант с акцентом на четвертом слоге «одновремЕнно» допустимым. **Однако эту точку зрения можно считать устаревшей.**

3) **Или может быть, значения или стилевые характеристики у слов разные, например:**

"Одичали над чаирами ничейными и шиповниками стали розы чайные. ОдноврЕменно (в одно и то же врЕмя) с приручением происходит рост одичания" (А. Вознесенский).

"И вкусы и запросы мои - странны, - Я экзотичен, мягко говоря: Могу одновремЕнно (и то и другое) грызть стаканы - И Шиллера читать без словаря" (В. Высоцкий).

Comment: Ударения у Вознесенского и Высоцкого объясняются исключительно стремлением попасть в ритм, и не надо здесь искать скрытых смыслов.

Comment: Это понятно, но  поискать скрытые смыслы никогда не помешает - в жизни и в языке  (как в живой и развивающейся  структуре)  нет ничего бессмысленного.

Comment: Мне кажется, все проще. Высоцкий, имевший все-таки сценическое образование, лучше владел классической культурой слова. Вознесенский был новатором - и в части ударения тоже. Он так слышал - и так фиксировал. Разговоры о том, что поэты ставят-де ударения, лишь бы в размер попало, отметаю сразу.

Comment: @Morkovkin Вы перепутали. Это у Вознесенского ударение классическое, а у Высоцкого - "как слышится". Но согласен, Высоцкому это не свойственно.

Answer (score 3):

**ОдновремЕнно** *и допуст.* **одноврЕменно**

Словарь трудностей русского языка. Ударение. Грамматические формы. с. 250 (Н. Еськова, Институт русского языка РАН, Москва 2014)

Такова современная тенденция в ударении (как и с соотв. прилагательными); я лично всегда употреблял только первый вариант.

**P. S.** А вообще... Надо пользоваться современной разновариантностью в ударении. Я уверенно говорю *одновремЕнно* только потому, что использую слово только в прямом значении совпадения во времени. В переносном же смысле (напр., при противопоставлении качеств чего-либо - "такой и одновременно сякой"), пожалуй, произносил бы с альтернативным ударением: по написанному мне в таком смысле читается, скорее, так. Но сам я в переносном смысле предпочитаю выражение "в то же время" (оно мне кажется менее формальным).

Comment: А кроме Еськовой кто-нибудь такое дает? При всем к ней уважении несколько преждевременно принижать исторический вариант, который у Зарвы еще идет как единственный (у неё, правда, почти все "единственные", но все-таки).

Answer (score 1):

Такое ударение допускается уже давно.

[В толковым словаре  Д.Н. Ушакова, 1935--1940 приводится вариант с ударением на четвертом слоге - ОДНОВРЕМЕ́ННЫЙ,](http://dic.academic.ru/contents.nsf/ushakov/)

А уже уже в 1960 году в словаре Ожегова фиксируется двойная норма ударения в слове «одновременный» и варианты произношения даны как равноправные, без указания на предпочтительность того или иного варианта.

Двойное ударение в слове «одновременный» фигурировало в «Орфоэпическом словаре», выпущенном издательством «Русский язык» в 1983 году Орфоэпический словарь, в словаре Российской Академии Наук (2003 год издания), словаре под редакцией Лопатина и многих других словарях и справочниках.

Answer (score 0):

На мой взгляд, современная норма пока еще одновр**е**менно. Во всех значениях. 
Одноврем**е**нно - разговорное. Тоже во всех. 
Даже в тех случаях, когда в словарях приводится два варианта, одновр**е**менно всегда идет первым - и даже не через союз "и", которым обычно соединяются варианты полностью равноправные.

Дифференциация значений по месту ударения - это, конечно, реальный в языке путь, но в данном случае ни на чем не основано, кроме смутных предположений.